# Tony Hawk Pro Skater 1 Down Hill Jam S-K-A-T-E Tape

Tags: ps1, tony-hawks-pro-skater

In Tony Hawk Pro Skater 1 on the Down Hill Jam map, how do I get the last letter E to spell skate? The E is up on a ledge and I've tried to use the ramp to the right of it which I'll try to do a grind on the pipe to try to get up there but I always end up falling/tripping.

Any suggestions on how to get the E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to come at the ramp you mentioned with a lot of speed. Try to catch the rail near its start.

Video: